# NSScrollView scrolling to the bottom of View

Tags: macos, nsscrollview

in Mac OS ap development, i have created a form using different textFields inside a scrollView. Now when i load that view, the scrollView automatically scrolls to the bottom and every time i need to scroll it up to View the content from starting. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default the document view of a scroll view has an origin in the lower left. This us generally true on OS X. 
If you prefer a document view that has origin in upper left, you need a custom view for the document view with an override of isFlipped returning YES.

Otherwise you can save state and scroll to the area programatically.